# Get page's messages from a certain date range - Facebook Opengraph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get the messages in a convertation, sent to a Facebook page, from a certain date, via the OpenGraph API.

for that, Im using the parameters "since" and "until".

```
{conversation_id}/messages?fields=message,from,created_time,shares,tags,attachments&since=4/12/2017 04:00:09 PM&until=4/12/2017 04:18:36 PM
```

[Example from Facebook Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=t_mid.1473145759490%3A1ddaaff01111a46489%2Fmessages%3Ffields%3Dmessage%2Cfrom%2Ccreated_time%2Cshares%2Ctags%2Cattachments%26since%3Dnow&version=v2.8)

this should return only the messages between these dates in the conversation,
and used to work both in my code and in the Facebook Graph Explorer.
but recently i noticed that i get **all the messages** since the beginning of the conversation.

my code uses graph version 2.6, but i tested it on Graph Explorer in other versions as well, all the results are the same.

was there any change in the API that prevents this ability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who come across this question who might want to know:
this issue was raised to Facebook as a bug, and their team accept it as a valid bug:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/420363721670492/

hopefully it will be solved soon